# avalanche invariants in an Abelian sandpile

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups

In the Abelian sandpile model, is the following statement true: the number of times the trigger site topples in an avalanche is invariant, that is it does not depend on the order of the toppling. The trigger site is the first critical site in an avalanche; toppling it creates the avalanche. Assume the sandpile is given on a regular grid (square grid in 2d, cubic grid in 3d, etc) and that all sites on the sides are the sink sites, which is the usual setup in simulations. I ran some numerical experiments with the 2d and 3d sandpiles and observed that the number of topplings of the trigger site was the same for two particular orderings of toppling, namely, parallel ordering and wave ordering.

Please provide the proof if possible, although a reference will be sufficient. If the statement is false, a counter-example would be useful.

Comment: It might be necessary to assume the sandpile is in a recurrent state. Feel free to make that assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is true, see Lemma 2.1 in [1].

A proof in the much more general setting of Abelian Networks can be found in [2] (Lemma 4.6).

[1] Anne Fey, Lionel Levine and Yuval Peres, Growth rates and explosions in sandpiles, Journal of Statistical Physics (2010) 138: 143--159 
     http://www.math.cornell.edu/~levine/growthrates.pdf

[2] Benjamin Bond and Lionel Levine, Abelian networks: foundations and examples
     http://www.math.cornell.edu/~levine/abelian-networks-I.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the references.